# Agglomerate time series data

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, time-series

I have AWS EC2 instance CPU utilization and other metric data given to me in CSV format like this:

```
Date,Time,CPU_Utilization,Unit
2016-10-17,09:25:00,22.5,Percent
2016-10-17,09:30:00,6.534,Percent
2016-10-17,09:35:00,19.256,Percent
2016-10-17,09:40:00,43.032,Percent
2016-10-17,09:45:00,58.954,Percent
2016-10-17,09:50:00,56.628,Percent
2016-10-17,09:55:00,25.866,Percent
2016-10-17,10:00:00,17.742,Percent
2016-10-17,10:05:00,34.22,Percent
2016-10-17,10:10:00,26.07,Percent
2016-10-17,10:15:00,20.066,Percent
2016-10-17,10:20:00,15.466,Percent
2016-10-17,10:25:00,16.2,Percent
2016-10-17,10:30:00,14.27,Percent
2016-10-17,10:35:00,5.666,Percent
2016-10-17,10:40:00,4.534,Percent
2016-10-17,10:45:00,4.6,Percent
2016-10-17,10:50:00,4.266,Percent
2016-10-17,10:55:00,4.2,Percent
2016-10-17,11:00:00,4.334,Percent
2016-10-17,11:05:00,4.334,Percent
2016-10-17,11:10:00,4.532,Percent
2016-10-17,11:15:00,4.266,Percent
2016-10-17,11:20:00,4.266,Percent
2016-10-17,11:25:00,4.334,Percent
```

As in evident, this is reported every 5 minutes. I do not have access to the aws-cli. I need to process this and report average utilization every 15 minutes for visualization. That is, for every hour, I need to find the average of the values in the first 15 minutes, the next fifteen minutes and so on. So, I will be reporting 4 values every hour.

A sample output would be:

```
Date,Time,CPU_Utilization,Unit
2016-10-17,09:30:00,14.517,Percent
2016-10-17,09:45:00,40.414,Percent
2016-10-17,10:00:00,33.412,Percent
2016-10-17,10:15:00,26.785,Percent
...
```

One way to do it would be to read the entire file (which has 10000+) lines, then for each date, find the values which belong to one window of 15 minutes, compute their average and repeat for all the values. This does not seem to be the best and the most efficient approach. Is there a better way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Is the file really too large to read it in completely? 10000 lines does not sound to big to read in a `numpy` array and for processing it there. I guess this should actually perform better than looping over the file and reading it line-by-line.

Comment: @jotasi No, it's not large. Even I considered the approach of reading the entire file as a Numpy array. How would I proceed then? Should I then read the rows belonging to a particular date and then proceed? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pandas is made to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your input data is actually pretty small, I'd suggest to read it in at once by use of [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). Then you can find the appropriate range by checking when a full quarter of an hour is reached and end by counting how many full quarters are left. Then you can use [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to get the array to a form with rows of quarters of hours and then average over those rows:

```
import numpy as np

# Read in the data:
data = np.genfromtxt("data.dat", skip_header=1,
                     dtype=[("date", "|S10"),
                            ("time", "|S8"),
                            ("cpu_usage", "f8")],
                     delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1, 2))

# Find the first full quarter:
firstQuarterHour = 0
while not (int(data[firstQuarterHour]["time"][3:5]) % 15 == 0):
    firstQuarterHour += 1
noOfQuarterHours = data[firstQuarterHour:].shape[0]/3

# Create a reshaped array
reshaped = data[firstQuarterHour:firstQuarterHour+3*noOfQuarterHours+1].reshape(
    (noOfQuarterHours, 3))

# Average over cpu_usage and take the appropriate dates and times:
cpu_usage = reshaped["cpu_usage"].mean(axis=1)
dates = reshaped["date"][:, 0]
times = reshaped["time"][:, 0]
```

Now you can use those arrays to for example save into another text file by use of [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).